# I have a problem with my new 4K monitor, in the morning or after it comes out of sleep mode, I get horizontal lines appearing for a while

Tags: nvidia, display, nvidia-geforce, 4k-monitor

I just got a new monitor, a **Samsung U32J59x** which is a 4K monitor (3840x2160). My video board is an **Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060**.

In the morning or after the monitor goes to sleep, when I wake the monitor up, I can see horizontal lines like shown in the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQtqZ-cw16M

Usually they are purple, I've seen them cyan too.

I've also seen the lines appear depending on which window is in the front (i.e. in some cases having window A in the front prevented the lines, having window B in the front and the lines appeared).

I tested the same computer & video board with a 4K TV (a specter) and never saw such problems. Also with my old monitor (an HD, so only 1920x1080) I never saw such a problem.

I tried to change the cable thinking maybe the old cable I had could be a problem. Since it works just fine after "it warms up" (some 20 seconds, see the video) then it works just fine and I never see those lines. So I would imagine that the board is fine and there are not interference along the cable.

Is there something I can do to fix the problem? Could the monitor have problems? (I can have it replaced)

Comment: I have a laptop that has a 4K display and a 2060 and experienced a [similar problem](https://superuser.com/q/1630188/1187720) dual bootong. I had to disable the laptop display and use Ubuntu on an external display. I do not get this problem on Windows however. Must be some kind of driver issue. Which version are you using?

Comment: @avneeshmishra I haven't tried that port in a  long time... I've been able to use that monitor using the HDMI2 port of the monitor without trouble. I just got another such monitor and plugged in the DisplayPort on that second monitor and it worked right in. It could have been a driver issue too, or at least the default settings which may not match 100% what the monitor expects.